# order of reporting of tests in testng report is random

Tags: webdriver, testng

This is how my testNG test looks like:-

```
public class orderTest{
    @Test
    public void meth1() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("1");
        Reporter.log("1");
    }
    @Test
    public void meth2() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("2");
        Reporter.log("2");
    }
    @Test
    public void meth3() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("3");
        Reporter.log("3");
    }
    @Test
    public void meth4() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("4");
        Reporter.log("4");
    }
}
```

When i run it on eclipse, the console shows as :-
1
2
3
4
PASSED: meth1
PASSED: meth2
PASSED: meth3
PASSED: meth4

But when i open the testNG report, click on reporter output link, it shows as :-
Reporter output -
meth1
1
meth4
4
meth3
3
meth2
2

Why the order is not correct in the testng report?
order of execution is 1,2,3,4 
but,
order of reporting is 1,4,3,2.

Comment: What version of `TestNG` are you using? Post the testng.xml file.

Comment: i am using TESTNG 6.8 jar, here is the xml file

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  
<!--suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="tests"-->

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
  <test name="UItests" preserve-order="false">
   <parameter name="browser" value="FIREFOX"/>
    <classes>
     <methods preserve-order="false">
        <class name="tests.orderTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If you want the classes and methods listed in this file to be run in an unpredictible order, set the preserve-order attribute to false.`

That is what the [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) documentation says, so unless the wrong spelling (not saying that mine is perfect :), that's a feature.

But it seems to me, that only the reporting order is unpredictable, the execution seems quite predictable.

The dtd says,

`@attr preserve-order If true, the classes in this tag will be run in the same order as
found in the XML file.`

so that matches what it actually does.

It's not wrong but maybe expected the other way round.

Seems to be a feature to make the reports more attractive :)

Answer (score 1):

It can also be displayed by **execution order in the output report**. To do so, your TestNG Reporter should implement IReporter.

A good plugin that uses it is **[ReportNG](http://reportng.uncommons.org/)**.
You can override it's ***generateReport*** method, to display the suites in the Html report, by their parent **XML** suite order, like so:

```
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectoryName) {
        ...
        Comparator<ISuite> suiteComparator = new TestSuiteComparator(xmlSuites);
        suites.sort(suiteComparator);
        ...
}
```

Where the ***TestSuiteComparator*** is as follow:

```
public class TestSuiteComparator implements Comparator<ISuite> {

    public List<String> xmlNames;

    public TestSuiteComparator(List<XmlSuite> parentXmlSuites) {
        for (XmlSuite parentXmlSuite : parentXmlSuites) {
            List<XmlSuite> childXmlSuites = parentXmlSuite.getChildSuites();
            xmlNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            xmlNames.add(parentXmlSuite.getFileName());
            for (XmlSuite xmlsuite : childXmlSuites) {
                xmlNames.add(xmlsuite.getFileName());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ISuite suite1, ISuite suite2) {
        String suite1Name = suite1.getXmlSuite().getFileName();
        String suite2Name = suite2.getXmlSuite().getFileName();
        return xmlNames.indexOf(suite1Name) - xmlNames.indexOf(suite2Name);
    }
}
```